# memory difference between c# new class instance vs calling method

Tags: c#, class, methods, instantiation

I am building a logging system within my c# application. Currently I have a logging method that I call which writes to log file. e.g.

```
Log("Hello World");
```

What I would like to do is write a class instead that I instantiate each time I want to Log something, and the constructor writes to the log file. e.g.

```
new WriteLog {Message="Hello World"};
```

The reason for this is more flexibility with parameters.

However I want to know if instantiating a class every time I log something has more memory cost than calling the method. Does every class that I instantiate persist in memory?

Comment: "The reason for this is more flexibility with parameters." - how?

Comment: "I am building a logging system within my c# application" - don't reinvent the wheel. Use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` instead.

Comment: `However I want to know if instantiating a class every time I log something has more memory cost than calling the method.` The short answer is "Yes".(not necessarily _much_ more - but more). The longer answer requires seeing more code.

Comment: "Does every class that I instantiate persist in memory?" - no. only as long as there is a reference to it. Otherwise it will be garbage collected eventually. Eventually means: it can be 2 minutes later

Comment: "and the constructor writes to the log file": this won't work with your code. The constructor runs **before** you set Message, so what would you log then?

Comment: If I had to use a logging library that requires me to write all the unnecessary characters that you have in your second solution, I'd immediately throw it away and use another one. Logging can be **extremely common** in some use cases, and having dozens of them will unavoidably clutter the code.

Comment: Creating a class means one extra reference in memory. But what you must do is to profile it to see the difference. Normally "no one cares".

Comment: Also I would say if you can avoid something IO related in constructor, you usually should. Also you can't make constructor async, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily they will persist but they will be removed in time by the garbage collector. Anyway unless you make extremely many calls in short time this shouldnt make any larger impact on memory.

I do however question if this is a good usage of a class. You are missusing a constructor as I see it and I dont think it will work with your code. A constructor should initiate data, not do actions such as log data. Also in your example the constructor is called before you assign the properties.

I think the real problem is why you feel a class has more flexibility in parameters.

Could it be you have not tried [named arguments and optional arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments). That might be something you might want to look up.

Comment: He seems to want to use the constructor for sending log messages **and the constructor writes to the log file**. The constructor is always called when you use new, but his assigning of properties will happend after the constructor is called.

Comment: Thank you @Achtung this is exactly what i needed. Answered my question and suggested correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Extension of the Logger class and you can use logger in the project to log exception or information.

**Sample Code**

```
public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    public static void LogCustomError(this ILogger logger, string message, params object[] args) => logger.LogError(message, args);
    public static void LogCustomError(this ILogger logger, Exception exception, string message, params object[] args) => logger.LogException(exception, message, args);

}
```

**Use**

```
public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
private readonly ILogger<ITestClass> _logger;

public TestClass(ILogger<TestClass> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

public voidTesMethod()
{
    try
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogException(ex, "Got error");
    }
}
```

}